# How to Override Any Key on Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, customization

As far as I know, Ubuntu's Key Bindings are all exposed on the files inside the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` folder. I've sometimes used the `pc` file to make some changes to some keys. However, I would like to know if there is a best practice on how to override the keys, preferably without overwriting these core files.

For example, is there a way of creating a user keyboard settings that would override the default one (like most good code editors do nowadays, such as VS Code)? It would also be much better if this method used the terminal or saved the settings in a file, so I could easily reproduce it in other machines.

**EDIT:**

More specifically, right now, in my use case, I'm looking to customize my `FN` key.

Answer (score 0):

I hate the fact that the menu bar swallows useful key mappings like alt-f (forward word) to do something rarely needed like open the file menu.

I searched and searched for ways to disable these alt menu keys and found nothing. Turns out you can kill them off using a bit of script in your init file.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Atom editor version 1.0.

```
# Get rid of the alt-menu shortcuts
atom.menu.template.forEach (t) ->
  t.label = t.label.replace("&", "")
atom.menu.update()
```

Comment: But is that only when using `Atom`? I was more on the lines of using the `X11` files actually. (Maybe there is a Gnome Tweaks Extension that does that?)